# Mounting OS X Server share on CentOS server

Tags: linux, macos, centos, smb, afp

I'm looking to mount a share from my OS X Server to use as a file dropbox for my CentOS 6 server. Would it be better to use SMB, AFP, or some other protocol to go about doing this reliably?

Comment: I would suggest using `ssh` - specifically `sshfs` - to mount a remote folder as a local one. This would even allow you to do it passwordlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I ended up creating public/private keys to be able to SSH into the Mac from the CentOS server without a password. Then I just used scp in a automatic script to send the files over WAN (daily backup via zip). Works great!